# How to ask for an input and bubble sort that input?

Tags: python, bubble-sort

It's my first time in coding in Python, I have created a code that bubbles sort a given list. This is my code:

```
def bubbleSort(alist):
    for passnum in range(len(alist)-1,0,-1):
        for i in range(passnum):
            if alist[i]>alist[i+1]:
                temp = alist[i]
                alist[i] = alist[i+1]
                alist[i+1] = temp

alist = ["hi",50,93,"/",77,31," ",55,20]
bubbleSort(alist)
print(alist)
```

I am trying to ask the user for the list instead of storing the list in the code, but I have no idea of how to do that in Python. Would someone help me out with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at Python's built-in methods and functions: [`raw_input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) and [`split`.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split)

```
def bubbleSort(alist):
    for passnum in range(len(alist)-1,0,-1):
        for i in range(passnum):
            if alist[i]>alist[i+1]:
                temp = alist[i]
                alist[i] = alist[i+1]
                alist[i+1] = temp

alist = raw_input('Enter the list to sort (seperated by spaces): ').rstrip()
alist = alist.split(' ')

bubbleSort(alist)
print(alist)
```

Comment: are you comparing `str` type in the `bubbleSort` function? Also this answer is already given by Caffeine.

Comment: Can a raw_input takes each element as a string? for example it takes "john Thomas" as one element

Answer (score 1):

One possible way is to read the arguments as commandline arguments. Some kind like this:

```
import sys

def main():
    # Some Code
    for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
         print(arg)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Another way is to read the input at runtime with "raw_input ()":

```
s = raw_input()
numbers = map(int, s.split())
```